# iPhone My program crashes after it play a mp4 file using the

Tags: iphone

I am making a program that loads videos from a server and then saves them locally.  The programmed worked fine when i was doing it synchronizely.  When I changed it to do it asynchronously , it would crash when the person return to the pre screen and try to press any of the buttons with a sig bad memory error.

What happens is the vedio loads and plays ok.  When they click the done button the methed

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;{
    [ mp stop]; 
//  [ mp release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: true];
}
```

exicutes and it goes to the pre screen.  Now on the pre screen, if they click on any button, i get a

I did the following
1. the file is big so I chnage my 
 [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLebngth:0]; to  [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:200000];, did not work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // construct the url
    NSString *mServerName=[ [ NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.besttechsolutions.biz/projects/golfflix/" ];
    NSString *mFullName=[ mServerName stringByAppendingString: mVedioName  ]; 
    NSURL *movieUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mFullName];

    // start the transmision
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:movieUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:100000000];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    [movieUrl release];
    [mServerName release];

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// background loading
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [connection release];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}



- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [connection release];


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Save vedio
    NSFileManager *mFile= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *filename=[ NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:mVedioName];
    [mFile createFileAtPath:filename contents: receivedData attributes:nil];
    [ receivedData release  ];

    // play it
    NSURL *fileUrl=[ NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename];
    if (mp==nil)
    {
        mp=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileUrl];
        [mp.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
        [self.view addSubview: mp.view];

        // Set movie player layout
        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        [mp play];
    }
    else {
        [mp stop];
        mp.contentURL=fileUrl;  
        [mp play];  
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    // movie reced save to file
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;{
    [ mp stop]; 
//  [ mp release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: true];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

any thoughts on this would be GREAT, ben stuck for days!!!!
Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are coming back to the pre screen then try to shift your code to

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOl)animated
     {
         //code 
     }
```

because the function viewDidLoad will be called only one time when the view is loaded.
 but the function viewWillAppear will be called whenever that view will appear.

Comment: Thank you I never heard of that method before, always learning new stuff :)